# WebRequest POST json parameter showing as Null on WebAPI

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, http-post, webrequest

I have a WebRequest that i am executing through a Windows CE project. I am able to send it through properly and i am able to see that it is hitting my WebApi. The only issue is that when the request comes through, the parameter is always null.

**Web API**

```
 [Route("")]
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] StopInfo stopInfo)
    {
        try
        {
            _scannerService.AddStops(stopInfo);
            return Ok(stopInfo);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**WebRequest**

```
private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        StopInfo s1 = new StopInfo();
        s1.ContactName = "Test";
        s1.CompanyName = "Ignite";
        s1.City = "Katy";
        s1.Addr1 = "22908 Mountain View";
        s1.Addr2 = "Suite 300";
        s1.State = "TX";
        s1.Zip = "77449";

        string uploadUrl = txtServerText.Text + "/api/stops";

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(s1);

        System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(uploadUrl);

        req.ContentType = "application/json";
        req.Method = "POST";

        byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(json);
        req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        System.IO.Stream os = req.GetRequestStream();
        os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); //Push it out there
        os.Close();
        System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();

        System.IO.StreamReader sr =
              new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Cast when creating HttpWebRequest object, like below example:

```
  HttpWebRequest req =    

        (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create((uploadUrl.ToString());
```

Also add the below properties to the HttpWebRequest object

```
req.Timeout = yourWebRequestTimeoutLimit
    req.KeepAlive = False
    req.Accept = "application/json"
    req.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(userName, password)
```